# Text Alignment not auto justifying in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

[image]

As you could see on the listview where the a subdescription of each should have a long string, the entire text just goes continuously to the right instead of properly aligning itself same as what happened on the description on the blue background.

I find it weird that it is not functioning the same way when it is rendered on the row of the listview.

Your insights would be welcome on how I could solve this issue of styling.

Here is a snippet of the renderRow component

```js
render() {
    var data = this.props.data;
    var commentor = data.user_id;
    var username = _.chain(this.props.userList)
                    .filter(function(item){
                      return item.id == commentor
                    })
                    .first()
                    .pick('username')
                    .value().username;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.avatar} source={require('../images/avatar.jpg')} />
          <View style={styles.inner_container}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: '500', fontSize: 13,textAlign:'justify'}}>{username}</Text>
            <Text style={{flex: 1, fontWeight: '300', fontSize: 14, marginTop: 5, textAlign:'justify',allowFontScaling: true}}>
            {data.comment}
            </Text>

          </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from adding the `Image` element in line with the text.

I suspect your you have `flexDirection: 'row'` in your `container` style, in which case the text will continue to the right instead of wrapping like it does with `flexDirection: 'column'`.

**Edit**

The original answer I provided was not the best way to handle the situation.

The right way to go is to wrap the text component in a `View` with `flexDirection: 'column'` in the styles. This way all of the content will use FlexBox and the text will wrap correctly.

In this case:

```
<View style={styles.inner_container}>
  <Text style={{fontWeight: '500', fontSize: 13}}>{username}</Text>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
    <Text style={{flex: 1, fontWeight: '300', fontSize: 14, marginTop: 5}}>
      {data.comment}
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

**Original answer**

I'm not sure it's the best solution, but you can make the flex direction 'column' for your container, then make the `avatar` position absolute and use margin to position the text where it needs to be. `renderRow` shouldn't need any modification.

Here's an example of the stylesheet:

```
var imageSize = 50;

var styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    avatar: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: imageSize,
        height: imageSize
    },
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        padding: 10
    },
    inner_container: {
        marginLeft: imageSize,
        paddingLeft: 15
    },
});
```

Note that I'm using `imageSize` to set the size of the image as well as margin for the text.

Comment: Thanks man, i added a view to wrap the description and have it styled with flexDirection: 'column' and also added flex:1 for it

Comment: Thats right on, but your solution does not guaranty that the text wont be hidden by the absolute `avatar`..! I've got that exact problem in my project and can't find a solution to it!

Comment: Not a solution that's workable if instead of an image, the element is variable width text

Comment: @Marc You're right. I've edited my answer to give a better solution to the problem.